# Will the apps made for honeycomb work in gingerbread?

Tags: android, compatibility, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am creating an app for honeycomb including all the widgets which was not present in gingerbread.(like NumberPicker etc).

Will this app work in gingerbread?

Comment: "I'm using stuff that doesn't exist in Gingerbread. Will it work in Gingerbread?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can try to include a custom made port of the NumberPicker into your application, but you'd probably have to write that yourself.